# Different hashes when using git hash-object --stdin in bash and cmd shells

Tags: windows, git

echo "Apple Pie" | git hash-object --stdin

when I issue the command in Git Bash shell,I get 23991897e13e47ed0adb91a0082c31c82fe0cbe5
and the same command in CMD Shell I get bb3918d5053fea31fc9a58fae1e5bdeabe3ec647

Can anyone tell me why they are different ? And more importantly if this behavior will have effect on my local git repository if I use the different shells on the same repository?

I am on windows 7 with git version 2.9.2.windows.1

Answer (score 0):

In Git bash shell, `echo "Apple Pie"` prints `Apple Pie\n`.

In CMD shell, it prints `"Apple Pie"\r\n`.

1. double quotation marks
2. newline

The contents are different so the hash values are not the same.

You could make the output into files by `echo "Apple Pie" > xxx.txt`. Open the file with editor like notepad++ that has hex mode. Double quotation is obvious. Observe the newline.